# EnvironmentVariables default value length is greater than 4096

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a rails app to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk(eb) environment

I got this error back:

```
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
2019-01-24 09:42:16    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2019-01-24 09:42:26    ERROR   Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Template format error: Parameter 'EnvironmentVariables' default value '[****]' length is greater than 4096.
2019-01-24 09:42:26    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
```

I found this

> The combined size of all environment properties cannot exceed 4,096
> bytes when stored as strings with the format key=value.

in the amazon docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html#environments-cfg-softwaresettings-console).

My environment properties key value combined is much bigger than 4096 chars.

as most of the values are credentials for API and Payments, thus I end up with just a dozen of keys.

My app work just fine in Heroku, there is no such limitation on the env variables. I am wondering what is the reason behind this restrictions in eb.

Is there anyone experience with this?

In my case, I would like to increase the limit (4096). I don't wanna change my code just to fit the eb restrictions.

I am also open for any kind of workaround to overcome this 4096 chars.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have a lot of long environment variable values that you can store as certificate files instead, see [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53991672/1753903)

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html#environments-cfg-softwaresettings-console) also say "Values can contain up to 256 characters. ", but, at this very moment I'm looking at a fully functional environment with several environment property values more than 400 characters each...

Answer (score 8):

Beanstalk uses Cloudformation underneath to provision environments. As a result, there is a limit on environment variables. You can not increase this limit because it is hard-coded in the kernel to `PAGE_SIZE`.

This is a nice [resource](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/configuration-with-ssm-parameter-store/) that explains an alternative approach for solving this problem.

Comment: I think I will go with hybrid ways to make sure I can run the app and see other challenges with eb as early as possible. After having done successfully I will try the approach you mentioned above. Thanks a lot.

Comment: From the same other than the linked resource. Fresh blog post on Aws::SSM https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/configuration-with-ssm-parameter-store/

Comment: @MathieuJ.Thanks. Updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Still, this remains a very inconvenient restriction.

Comment: did any one found any other workaround except Aws::SSM