# Elastic Beanstalk Maximum Environment Variable Length

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have difficulty trying to set up over 100 environment variables in my production Elastic Beanstalk running Django. The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html#environments-cfg-softwaresettings-console) mention that

> The combined size of all environment properties cannot exceed 4,096
> bytes when stored as strings with the format key=value.

To my understanding there are 3 ways to set env vars in ELB.

1. Through `eb cli` e.g `eb setenv key=value`(Doesn't work because it'll error out because of maximum length after reaching the maximum no. of characters)
2. Through the EB GUI Configuration > Software > Env variables (Doesn't work for the same reason above)
3. Through

   option_settings:

   - option_name: CUSTOM_ENV
     value: staging

I imagine 3) would fail for the same reason too.

I'm now experimenting with downloading my **variables.env** file from my S3 bucket and then replacing **/opt/python/current/env** with it

```
files:
  # Private key
  "/opt/python/current":
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    authentication: "S3Auth"
    source: ****/env
```

the idea being that ELB injects environment variables through that file. Unfortunately, the deployment errors out (permission error).

Is there a way to circumvent the 4096 bytes limitation on ELB environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to increase it within EBS as its a hard-coded limit ([EnvironmentVariables default value length is greater than 4096](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54344236/environmentvariables-default-value-length-is-greater-than-4096)). They also link to a workaround there.

Otherwise you could try to reduce the amount of characters used, e.g. TRUE -> 1, as described in this article https://insights.project-a.com/aws-elastic-beanstalk-when-not-to-use-it-b04dc95b2e9c. But of course this is not scalable and you might run into the same problem again.